# rgraph x axis is not accurate to its ticks

Tags: javascript, margin, padding, rgraph

Helo,

I want to do padding-left to the xaxis because the zero number doesn't start at the beginning of the graph.

[image]
Anyone know how to do this?

**In chrome it is being render in advance correctly where in IE it doesn't as I describe.

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: Can you put an example page online?

Comment: http://edu.lnet.org.il/RgraphTest/appTemplate1.html

Comment: I pulled out the code from both of the IE charts on the page and it rendered fine. You could try using only one set of code for the chart render instead of having an IE version and other-browsers version. If nothing else that would make things slightly easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I didn't understand how did you make it render fine. I am still encountering the zero number to be display left to y axis (I marked it with red color at the attached image).

Comment: Thank you for replaying, I solved the problem by adding direction:ltr to my canvas tag.